# AutomaticAuthenticate for ASP.NET IdentityServer4 on open routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a few endpoints in an ASP.NET core application that's also hosting IdentityServer.
When I issue a JWT token to a client, and that client calls an [AllowAnonymous] endpoint with the JWT as a bearer token, the User principal is empty. It looks like the token isn't being parsed by any middleware, and there doesn't seem to be an option to specify always attempting to parse a JWT.

Is there a way to get this handled automatically or do I need to use the .AddJwtBearer extension? If the latter I can't seem to find an easy way for me to populate the signingkey such that it matches the ones configured for identity server.

```
var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    // The signing key must match!
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = ?? signing keys from Identity Server,
 
    // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidIssuer = // I guess this is typically the public URL for this instance,
  
    // Validate the token expiry
    ValidateLifetime = true,
 
    // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
};
 
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
});
```

I would guess that for the SigningKey I could pass through the X509 that I'm configuring on IdentityServer via the [x509SecurityKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.x509securitykey?view=azure-dotnet) class

Comment: Have you added  app.UseAuthentication(); to the client startup class?

Comment: Yes, I have app.UseIdentityServer(); app.UseAuthentication(). When configuring services I setup IdentityServer (services.AddIdentityServer(....)) then call services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(opt => {});
Still when I present a bearer token the User is just the default user on an unprotected endpoint

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

UseJwtBearerAuthentication is obsolete. Configure JwtBearer authentication with AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer in ConfigureServices.

Also make sure  app.UseAuthentication(); is added in your startup class.

I find a best practice is to always host IdentityServer, client and API on separate ASP.NET Core instances, because otherwise its hard to reason about what is what. IdentityServer issues its own User and cookie so I think your system is confused about what user to use?

Reference:

- [JwtBearerAppBuilderExtensions.UseJwtBearerAuthentication Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.jwtbearerappbuilderextensions.usejwtbearerauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [Auth 2.0 Migration announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310)